# Run GET Request in While Loop or Similar

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, get

basically i want to create an loop that makes GET Requests until a Condition is there and then use the Data from the GET Request.

I got this code:

```
checkAndAcceptPickup(23);


async function checkAndAcceptPickup(id: number) {
    while (!isDone) {
        getPickupsFromStore(id).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}


async function getPickupsFromStore(id: number) {
    const response = await axios.get(`URL`)
    return response.data
}
```

But unfortunately nothing gets console logged, what am i doing wrong?

I tried to use a setInterval Method but that was scuffed too because of the await in the GET Request.

It should do:

Wait for GET Request => Check Condition => New GET Request....

Comment: Did you forget to call `myCall`? Looks like your loop will never be entered.

Comment: Also, you need to await `getPickupsFromStore`, otherwise it'll repeat the request every tick (very bad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the `getPickupsFromStore` function to complete before continuing the while loop.

It should look like this:

```js
async function checkAndAcceptPickup(id: number) {
    while (!isDone) {
        await getPickupsFromStore(id).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg, I'm so embarrassed... I overlooked that...
Thank you, will accept in 5 mins